# Minimizing the FaceRecognizer loading time

Tags: opencv

I'm following the example here:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_save_load.html

```
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model0 = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
model0->train(images, labels);
model0->save("faces_at.yml");    // save the model to faces_at.yaml
```

The issue is that the size of the saved file is big and it increases as the number inputs(which I train my model on) increases. Is there ANY way that I could reduce the file size? Because of the nature of my application, I need to load my predictor repeatedly which makes everything very slow. 
Once I've saved the file, I'm not doing any training and I'm using my loaded faceRecognizer for prediction only.

When I look into the YAML file, it seems that one of the things the model saves, is the following:

```
eigenvectors: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 10304
   cols: 29
```

Where 29 is the number of inputs and 10304 =92x112 the resolution of the images. Does the algorithm need this data for its prediction?

Can I modify what is being saved and what is being loaded so that I could reduce the amount of data required to be saved? If so, what do need to save and where should I change?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to reduce the size of the input faces. A 92x112 image seems small but the recognition should work fine on a much smaller image.

Comment: the problem is that even then it would be still dependent on the number of samples. I don't understand why the eigen vectors have 29(sample size) columns and 10304(92x122) rows

Comment: they will always have as many rows as there are pixels and you have way too many pixels. Twenty nine eigenvectors is not a lot but you can tell it to save fewer. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html#FaceRecognizer%20:%20public%20Algorithm